# Question in the proof of the Brower fix point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology, analytic-geometry

One can show that for any given homology theory $H$ with non-trivial coefficient group $G$ there does not exist a retract  $\partial B^n \subset B^n$. Brower's fix point theorem states that any continuous map $f:B^n\to B^n$ has at least one fixpoint. If we now assume by contradiction that $f(x) \neq x \space (\forall x \in B^n) $ then one can define $r: B^n \to \partial B^n$ by taking the ray $r_{f(x),x}$ from $f(x)$ to $x$ and defining $r(x)=r_{f(x),x} \cap \partial B^n$. Obvisouly we have $r\mid_{\partial B^n}=id_{\partial B^n}$.

**Question:**
Why is r continuous?

**Edit:**
I'm not seeking an intuitive answer as I already have an intuitive understanding on what is going on, but rather an explicit proof. If possible not an $\epsilon - \delta$ one.

Comment: You can write $$r(x) = f(x) + t(x)\cdot \bigl(x - f(x)\bigr),$$ where $t(x) \geqslant 1$ (since the intersection of the ray with the sphere can't happen before the ray reaches $x$). Assuming that we use the Euclidean norm, we get a quadratic equation for $t(x)$. Since the other solution of that equation is $\leqslant 0$, you can determine the sign in $t(x) = \frac{b(x) \pm \sqrt{d(x)}}{2a(x)}$, which shows the continuity of $t$. A little tedious, but not too bad.

Comment: approved, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate explicitly the intersection between the line defined by $x$, $f(x)$ and the border of the ball.

The line in parametric form is
$$t\longmapsto f(x)+(x-f(x))t.$$
The condition "the point is in the border" is
$$\|x+(f(x)-x)t\| = 1$$
(or any other radius $R$).

Comment: this certainly answers the question, thank you.